# Storing duplicate keys in a linked hashmap

Tags: duplicates, key, multimap

Ima reading an excel file as part of that iam creating a linked hashmap of integer and map.
My key is Integer and value is  map.

The problem here is when my Integer value is duplicated the the map is taking only single entry but i need two entries to be sustained.

Could someone help in resolving my issue.

I have googled to know abour multimap but sincerioly not able to get the syntax and jar files to include.Attaching my code for reference.`

```
package dao;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.MultiKeyMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.multimap.ArrayListValuedHashMap;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;




public class ReadWriteExcelFile {

    static ArrayList<Map<Integer,Map<String,String>>> data_list = new ArrayList<Map<Integer,Map<String,String>>>();

    //static ArrayList<String> names_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    static Map<String,String> names_Map;
    static ArrayList<String> header_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

    public static void main(String[] k) throws java.lang.Exception {

        ReadWriteExcelFile.readXLSXFile();
        ReadWriteExcelFile.writeXLSXFile();

    }

    public static void readXLSXFile() throws IOException {

        String excelFilePath = "D:/xxxyy.xlsx";

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

        XSSFSheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        String mainlabel = null;

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Row nextRow = iterator.next();

            Iterator cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();



            Map<Integer,Map<String,String>> temp = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Map<String,String>>();


            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                String mainlabelholder = mainlabel;
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();

                if (cell.getCellType() == cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING ) {
                    mainlabel= cell.getStringCellValue();
                    names_Map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    names_Map.put(mainlabelholder, cell.getStringCellValue());


                }

                else if (cell.getCellType() == cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC && !cell.equals(null)) {

                    //problem here temp not storing duplicate key 

                    temp.put((int) cell.getNumericCellValue(),names_Map);




                }

            } // end of cell iterator


            if (temp.size() != 0)
                data_list.add(temp);
            mainlabel=null;
            System.out.println("data List" + data_list);
            System.out.println("data List" + data_list.size());
            System.out.println("");

        } // end of iterator

    }

    static String year = "2018";

    static String fiscal_year = "2018";

    public static void writeXLSXFile() throws IOException {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Quota");
        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("NAME");
        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("AMOUNT)");
        header.createCell(2).setCellValue("CLOSEDDATE");
        header.createCell(3).setCellValue("TYPE");
        header.createCell(4).setCellValue("OWNERID");
        header.createCell(5).setCellValue("FISCALQUARTER");
        header.createCell(6).setCellValue("FISCALYEAR");
        header.createCell(7).setCellValue("FISCAL");
        header.createCell(8).setCellValue("PAGAMENTO_ID__C");
        header.createCell(9).setCellValue("QUOTA__C");
        int row = 1;
        int day = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < data_list.size(); i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < data_list.get(i).size(); j++) {

                    Row temp = sheet.createRow(row++);
                    // temp.createCell(0).setCellValue("Quota " + ((j / 3) + 1)
                    // + " " + fiscal_year);
                    temp.createCell(0).setCellValue("Quota " + ((j + 1) + " " + fiscal_year));
                    temp.createCell(1).setCellValue(data_list.get(i).keySet().toArray()[j].toString());
                    temp.createCell(2).setCellValue((day) + "/" + (j + 1) + "/" + year);
                    // temp.createCell(3).setCellValue(revenue);
                    Map map = (Map) data_list.get(i).values().toArray()[j];
                    //Map<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    //temp1.putAll(data_list.get(i).values().toArray()[j]);
                    //temp1= data_list.get(i).values().toArray()[j];
                    temp.createCell(3).setCellValue(map.values().toArray()[0].toString());
                    // temp.createCell(3).setCellValue(names_list.get(i+1));
                    temp.createCell(4).setCellValue(map.keySet().toArray()[0].toString());
                    temp.createCell(5).setCellValue(((j / 3) + 1));
                    temp.createCell(6).setCellValue(fiscal_year);
                    temp.createCell(7).setCellValue(fiscal_year + " " + ((j / 3) + 1));
                    // temp.createCell(8).setCellValue(names_list.get(i) + " " +
                    // revenue + " " + ((j / 3) + 1) + " " + fiscal_year);
                    //temp.createCell(9).setCellValue(data_list.get(i).get(j));

                     temp.createCell(8).setCellValue(map.keySet().toArray()[0].toString() + " " +
                     map.values().toArray()[0].toString() + " " + ((j / 3) + 1) + " " + fiscal_year);
                    //temp.createCell(9).setCellValue(data_list.get(i).get(j));



                    temp.createCell(9).setCellValue(data_list.get(i).keySet().toArray()[j].toString());
                }
            }
        //}

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\out\\Quotacsvmodi.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question in simple words and reduce the code sample to a [minimal, complete, and verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Map<Integer,Map<String,String>> temp = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Map<String,String>>(); is my map and temp.put((int) cell.getNumericCellValue(),names_Map); Iam trying to put
integer and map of string,string as a key value pair.but when my key is duplicated the map is holding only single entry but i want both

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [What is difference between HashMap and HashMultimap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222029/what-is-difference-between-hashmap-and-hashmultimap) - a HashMap can only contain one value per key, so you probably need the MultiMap which is provided by [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava#Multimap)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump an old thread but I just ran into this issue myself and did a quick search to find no real good answer other than Multimap.. well I don't currently have access to it and I'm not looking to add another library so here is what I came up with;

```
        LinkedList<Map..> myList = new LinkedList<>();
```

[LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) will keep track of index and has a wide variety of utility such as addFirst, removeLast, etc...

If for whatever reason this does not work for you - you could also use a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and manually manage the index via the Key

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, Map<K, V>> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        myMap.put(1, new Map<K, V>());
```

Hope this helps!