# Transfer from Set<Tuple> Data to HashMap (Java)

Tags: java, redis, hashmap, set

I try to extract a sorted set Data from Redis to Java.

I have a 100,000 size of data in Redis.

When i extracts a data from Redis, **the Set type in Java value size is 100,000**. And then, All of data is added as a **HashMap**. 
The HashMap size should be 100,000, but **it's size returns as 63,241**. **I don't know why all of data can't be added as a HashMap.**

Here is my source Code.

```
public HashMap<String, String> getSortedSet() {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {    

            Set<Tuple> a = jedis.zrangeWithScores(key, 0, -1);
            System.out.println("First : " + a.size()); //size is 100,000

            //This is repeated 100,000 times. 
            for (Tuple tuple : a) {
                map.put(key + ":" + tuple.getScore(), tuple.getElement());
            }
            System.out.println("Map Size : " + map.size()); //size is 63,241
        }

        return map;
    }
```

Comment: Clearly because there are duplicate keys. A `Set<Tuple>` has unique tuples (score and element) while a Map only has unique keys (score)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks! Then, i should use a another type for saving data.

Comment: There is guava multimap.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19222029/1270789) on `HashMap` versus `HashMultimap`.

Comment: what is `key` btw? you use it in your code, but you have not declared it... than your method name is `getSortedSet` but you return a `HashMap`